# Unittests marked with @unittest.skip are not marked under nosetests

Tags: python-3.x, nose, python-unittest

When one uses @unittest.skip and runs tests, generally the skipped tests are marked with a small s, and the tally is reported at the end.

If I run the tests with nosetests, the tests simply disappear, leaving no trace of their existence in the final report. I tried with --no-skip, but it didn't change anything.

How can I have the "s" marks and the total skipped while running under nose?

Comment: you have a 41.6k rep but the correct answer isn't marked as such?

Comment: @Clintm: I have 41.6k rep but I don't spend my whole day on SO?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Looks like you have to provide a reason for skipping a test:

```
from unittest import skip

@skip
def foo_test():
    pass
```

gives what you observed:

```
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Ran 0 tests in 0.000s

OK
```

while:

```
from unittest import skip

@skip("nose likes having good reasons")
def foo_test():
    pass
```

will give you:

```
foo_test.foo_test ... SKIP: nose likes having good reasons

----------------------------------------------------------------------
Ran 1 test in 0.003s

OK (SKIP=1)
```

Answer (score 1):

I mark tests to be skipped in `nose` via the `@nottest` decorator (at the test method level), and they are marked with an **S** and listed in the number of skipped tests at the end.

To get that decorator you import thusly:

```
from nose.tools import nottest
```

Comment: there's no way of having the same result with the ones marked unittest.skip ?

Comment: Looks like @Oleksiy provided info on the reason it wasn't working with `unittest.skip`. I've always used `@nottest` in conjunction with `unittest`-extended nose tests, but certainly if you are already using `unittest.skip` it makes sense to try to keep that.